# How to give a dynamic value between a text in xsl?

Tags: xslt-1.0

For example,

```
<img src="some-image.gif" title="Here"+<xsl:value-of select="myVar"/>+"is the value"/>
```

This doesn't work.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do:

```
<img src="some-image.gif" title="Here{$myVar}is the value"/>
```

Read more about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates).